# Automatic text / HTML annotation / highlighting

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, summarization

Nowadays there are softwares which, when provided a text or a html document page, will output a summary.

I wonder if there exist anything to automatically annotate (or at least highlight) the same documents.

The idea is to be able to keep the full text, but highlight the most meaningful parts (somehow like a summarisation tool would do I guess). And maybe provide additional inferred insights (?)

Also I would like to know how it works if it exists :) Would it really be very different of summarization, or is it just the same principles with a different "output format"?

I'm looking for something to annotate HTML documents, like AnnotatorJS is designed for, looking like this:

[image: WritingPod]

Comment: Looking for research paper? library? product?

Comment: @matcheek anything that can give me any insight of this. Just wonder if it is worth for my company to invest any time in it or if this is too hard to solve for a small startup. I guess more research papers as SO is not really to discuss commercial products, and most products are probably backed by research papers right?

Comment: Unless you want to carry out your own research  I would check the current advances in the field first. There are tons of already written libraries https://github.com/miso-belica/sumy or even ready frameworks 
http://gallery.azureml.net/Experiment/Text-Classification-Step-3B-of-5-unigrams-TF-IDF-feature-extraction-2?share=1

See the last link for diagrams that quickly describe the whole process.
In brief, assuming you have not touched on text summaries before, you will be working with things like: vector space model, n-grams, feature vectors.

Comment: thanks @matcheek I'll take a loot at these links. Sumy references an impressive list of existing tools. I'm not involved at all in summerization but have some experience in machine learning and search engines text analyzers so hopefully I'll be able to understand all that :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but it can lead to what you want. The first suggestion is looking at [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/). It provides a great annotation framework and as long as you don't want to program anything for it, it is easy to use. The second thing is to search for summarization plug-ins for GATE. GATE has been around for such a long time that I am sure someone has already implemented a summarization plug-in for it.